# Converting a list of data into table format in R

Tags: arrays, r

I currently have data that is structured in the following way

```
ID,   Question, Answer   
abc,  123,      1,  
abc,  456,      2,  
abc,  789,      1,  
abc,  000,      4,  
def,  123,      2,  
def,  456,      3,  
def,  789,      1,    
def,  000,      2,
```

I would like to convert it into a table format as follows

```
    123 456 789 000
abc  1   2   1   4  
def  2   3   1   2
```

Basically with the `ID` as rows and the `Question` as columns.

What would be the most effective R code to achieve this?

Comment: This is a simple long to wide conversion: use e.g. `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(ID) %>% spread(Question, Answer)`; lots of details/options/alternatives in the linked post.

Comment: Thank you Maurits for the answer and the link. Very helpful.